# How do I listen keyevents?

Tags: java

I am trying to build Pac-Man. I have tried this to listen keyevents and move Pac-Man:

Game class:

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game gui = new Game();
        gui.start();
    }
    Pacman pacman = new Pacman(750,750);
    public Game(){
        super("PacMan");
        setSize(800,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        pacman.render(g);
    }
    public void start(){
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN)
            pacman.down = true;
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP)
            pacman.up = true;
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT)
            pacman.left = true;
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT)
            pacman.right = true;
        pacman.move();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

}
```

Pacman class:

```
public class Pacman extends Rectangle {
    public boolean right;
    public boolean left;
    public boolean up;
    public boolean down;
    public Pacman(int x, int y){
        setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
    public void move(){
        if(right)
            x += 100;
        else if(left)
            x -= 100;
        else if(up)
            y -= 100;
        else if(down)
            y += 100;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I dont know where am I doing wrong. When I am pressing the arrow keys, pacman doesn't move. What can I do to detect arrow keys when pressed and move Pacman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your code in `keyPressed` method instead of `keyTyped`.

As you can read in the documentation:

> KEY_TYPED (is only generated if a valid Unicode character could be generated.)

and also :

> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about character input. In the simplest case, a key typed event is produced by a single key press (e.g., 'a') [...] **No key typed events are generated for keys that don't generate Unicode characters (e.g., action keys, modifier keys, etc.).**

Also, replace `VK_KP_UP` and so on with `VK_UP`. Remove KP

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) and also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) for learning more about key events and listener

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! It helped and I now understand what is wrong about what have I done.

Comment: Happy about that. Good programming!